# How can Jenkins list merge request titles from Gitlab in build report

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, gitlab

Our SCM system contains a Git repository managed in Gitlab as well as Jenkins that contains a job that builds the master branch.  The build job in Jenkins is triggered manually as a build is done when a version of the software is considered completed.

Our process is as follows:

1. The developer pulls the master branch and branches off it so that the dev can perform the enhancement or address a bug.
2. Once the work has been coded, tested and signed off, a merge request is created in Gitlib so that the branch that the developer worked on can be merged into master.
3. A fellow developer does code review and if happy with the code, approves the merge request and the code is merged into master.

Once a version of the software is considered completed, a build is triggered in Jenkins manually.

What I've seen is that once the build is complete, a list of commit titles is displayed under changes.  I have no idea what generates this list, but this is something that appears out of the box in Jenkins.

See the screenshot below as to what this looks like.  Note that I blanked out the actual commit messages themselves as well as any developer names, etc.

[Jenkins changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVMn.png)

Is there a way for Jenkins to rather show all the merge request titles that make up that build since the last build instead of the commit titles?

This will allow the person that triggered the build to confirm visually that all issues that they expect to be in the build, are actually in the build.  The commit messages that are currently displayed produce a lot of noise so a list of merge request titles would be far more valuable.

Comment: You mentioned "a list of commit titles is displayed under changes". Can you describe how you are getting this list in jenkins (is there any script you are using in jenkins) ? - pls edit your question with this answer. If we know this, we can try for your need.

Comment: I've edited my question.  As indicated above, I have no idea what generates this list, but this happens in Jenkins out of the box.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot ?

Comment: Added screenshot to post

Comment: Thank you Glen. Let me see what I can do for you !!